# Bootstrap 3 Collapse events not triggering

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a menu for mobile devices and am trying to use Bootstrap 3's collapse feature.

I already have a collapse working on a different page, so I copied over the structure, gave the panel group a different id, and changed the 'data-parent's and 'panel-collapse' ids appropriately. However, this new accordion just does not work. The 'in' class does not get applied to the target .panel-collapse div, and the hrefs (ex: #navCollapse(x) ) are appearing in the address bar, instead of the normal functionality.

Here is the problematic code. (trimmed to 2 panels for brevity. Still not working as is)

```
<div class='panel-group' id='accordionNav' >
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
      <a data-parent='#accordionNav' data-toggle='collapse' href="#navCollapse1">  <h3>About</h3></a>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-collapse collapse in'  id='navCollapse1'>
      <div class='panel-body'>
        <p>Test test ets ejkfbduskfgsalf jydasl</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
      <a data-parent='#accordionNav' data-toggle='collapse' href="#navCollapse2"><h3>Donors</h3></a>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-collapse collapse' id='navCollapse2'>
      <div class='panel-body'>
        <p>Test test ets ejkfbduskfgsalf jydasl</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works: http://jsbin.com/EvesENi/1/edit It's your code. The new page may be missing the jQuery. Check to see.

Comment: jQuery is definitely on the page, as on certain pages, I have another accordion working just fine, along with other scripts.